# supervisord event listener

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm trying to configure an event listener for supervisord but can't get it to work.
I just want to listen for PROCESS_STATE changes and run some python code triggering an urllib2request.

In my .conf I have:

```
[eventlistener:statechanges]
command=python listener.py
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

And in listener.py:

```
def run():    
    runFunc() # Function to trigger an urllib2request

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Then the trigger won't start, it just enters the FATAL state after some retries.

```
statechanges entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Any ideas or does someone have an example of how to write a listener for supervisord?

Answer (score 6):

You can't just print random strings, supervisord listens at the stdout :)

How about this example from the docs:

```
import sys

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
    while 1:
        write_stdout('READY\n') # transition from ACKNOWLEDGED to READY
        line = sys.stdin.readline()  # read header line from stdin
        write_stderr(line) # print it out to stderr
        headers = dict([ x.split(':') for x in line.split() ])
        data = sys.stdin.read(int(headers['len'])) # read the event payload
        write_stderr(data) # print the event payload to stderr
        write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK') # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    import sys
```

http://supervisord.org/events.html#example-event-listener-implementation

Comment: Ok, I've replaced the print with an urllib2request to a specified url. Now the trigger goes into the FATAL state, but manages to send some requests first.

Answer (score 0):

In ash:

```
command=sh -c 'echo "READY"; while read -r line; do echo "$line"; supervisorctl shutdown; done'
```