# supervisord: How to stop supervisord on PROCESS_STATE_FATAL

Tags: supervisord

I'm using supervisord to manage multiple processes in a docker container.
However, one process is always the 'master', and the others are monitoring and reporting processes.
What I want to do is kill supervisord if the master process fails to start after startretries.

What I tried to do is use eventlistener to kill the process:

```
[eventlistener:master]
events=PROCESS_STATE_FAIL
command=supervisorctl stop all
```

But I don't think the events subsystem is this sophisticated.  I think I need to actually write an event listener to handle the events.
Is that correct? Is there a simpler way to kill the entire supervisord if one of the processes kicks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

```
[eventlistener:quit_on_failure]
events=PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
command=sh -c 'echo "READY"; while read -r line; do echo "$line"; supervisorctl shutdown; done'
```

Especially for docker containers, it would literaly be a killer to have a simple straightforward shutdown on errors. Container should go down when processes die.

Comment: You can use bash and $PPID so that you don't need to use supervisorctl: `/bin/bash -c "echo READY; while read line; do kill $PPID; sleep 300; kill -9 $PPID; done"`

Answer (score 0):

Answered by:
[supervisord event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085623/supervisord-event-listener)

The command parameter MUST be an event handler, can't be a random command.